# Array inside an array with a single row and multiple columns

Tags: php, arrays

I have this part of my project where there's an array inside an array, but the thing is the array inside the array (sorry if this sounds confusing) has only 1 row and multiple columns. I need to get each column value, but I can't seem to find a way.

Here's what my array looks like

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [ID,DATE,ITEM_1,ITEM_2] => 50770,2017-11-16,5,1
>           )
>   )

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `echo array[0]['ID'] `?

Comment: I already tried this, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode key and value and combine to new array

```
$res = array_map(function($x) { 
  return array_combine(
    explode(',', key($x)), 
    explode(',', current($x))); }, 
  $arr);
echo $res['ID'];
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/925503)